# Coveo multi-list - find if field has only one value

Tags: coveo

I'm using several multi-list fields in my searches, and they work great to say "field = value" and it finds a matching value in the list. What I need now, though, is to check if the value I'm looking for is the only one in the list.

Example: a multi-list of states. In the usual scenario, I want to check if Virginia has been selected. In this new scenario, I want to check if the list contains Virginia ONLY...if Maryland is also selected, for example, then the result would not be returned.

Is there a length value that could be checked to find out how many selections are in the field? Then it'd be easy to say "AND length = 1" in addition to my standard query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no search operator to query the number of values in a multi value field in a Coveo index.

If your query only contains one value for a given multi value field, it would be possible to achieve your goal with another field containing the same values but not configured as a multi value field.

Exemple for a query @multivaluefield=="virginia" AND @normalfield=="virginia".
If @multivaluefield and @normalfield values are "virginia", the document will be returned.
However, if their values are "virginia;maryland", the query on @multivaluefield will return the document but the query on @normalfield will filter it out as the field doesn't contain only "virginia".

Comment: Since I've already designated my actual multi-value field as such in Coveo, I assume I'd need to create a new computed field to bring in the same field result, mark it as not multi-value, and then I can do the comparison you're talking about? (This would make a good feature request potentially too... :) )

Comment: Exactly. Use the same computed field class with a different field name and configuration for the @normalfield of my example.

Comment: Checking the SearchProvider.Custom.config, I see an example of how this could work built in...would this do it? <field fieldName="normalFieldName" sourceField="multivalueFieldName" referencedFieldName="ID">Coveo.SearchProvider.ComputedFields.ReferencedFieldComputedField, Coveo.SearchProviderBase</field> --- then I don't need to program anything, this would just read it in? Or is it better to just build a computed field in code?

Comment: The referencefielscomputedfield is only used when the original itel field contains IDs linking to other items in the content tree. How do you index the multivaluefield originally?

Comment: It's a multi-list, so it's just storing IDs. Originally it was just doing it as text, until you reminded me I had to declare the fields as multiValue=true. So if I got back to the original version of the field handling, I'd have a list of IDs as a string and could do the comparison that you suggest. I'll play around with it but I think I've got a path forward.